# Android disable WebView Actionmode

Tags: android

I am working on an application for Android Honeycomb 3.0 i.e. for the tablets. My application is basically a book where each chapter comes in the form of Webview. Now when we long press any word the action bar changes automatically with several options like - Select All, copy, share ,find etc.

HOW DO I DISABLE THAT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

Comment: @user1143989 how it works? please share your code.i too need some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
private OnLongClickListener listener = new OnLongClickListener() 
{      
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
        {           
            return true;      
        }   
};
```

Returning "true" fixed my problem. Hope it helps you.